# Unable to insert PowerShell variables from array into Invoke-Sqlcmd call

Tags: powershell, invoke-sqlcmd

I have an array that loops through a string assigning values to elements. If I then assign those elements to a variable and pass that variable into the invoke-sqlcmd I get an error. However, if I assign the value directly to the variable and pass it in it works fine:

Assign value to array:

```
for ($i=0; $i -lt $somearray.length; $i++) {
    $somearray[$i] = $somearray[$i].Replace('$(query)', $query.text)
}
```

Lets say somearray[0] = "select * from DB". We'll assign to a variable:

```
$query = somearray[0]
```

Now I pass this to my `Invoke-Sqlcmd`:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $query -Database "local" -ServerInstance "somedb" |
    Export-Csv ".\somefile.csv"
```

This fails:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd : Could not find stored procedure 'select * from ALERTS'.
At C:\Migration\ExportTool\ExportTool\Gavs.ps1:95 char:17
+ ...             Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $query -Database $db -ServerInstance ...
```

However, if I do this:

```
$query = "select * from DB"

Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $query -Database "local" -ServerInstance "somedb" |
    Export-Csv ".\somefile.csv"
```

it works perfectly.

Comment: `somearray[0]` -> `$somearray[0]`?

Answer (score 0):

So the reason appears to be, if you do this:

```
$query = somearray[0]
```

When you view $query in the Invoke-sql command it looks like this:

```
"select * from DB"
```

And when you do this:

```
$query = "select * from DB"
```

It looks like this:

```
select * from DB
```

So directly referencing a string removes the quotes in the Invoke-sqlcmd command. Seems very odd.

Hope this helps someone in the future.